# How to load values in bash file to a cpp file?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have mentioned ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE in bashrc file using export command...I want to use those values in one of my cpp files...How can i dircetly access those values??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350745/how-to-load-values-in-bash-file-to-a-cpp-file??/) by [harrynick](https://answers.ros.org/users/44792/harrynick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is not really related to ROS, but I'm going to answer as if you are using your C++ file as part of a ROS node. In that case you can use `roslaunch` to start your node, and in your launch file you can read the value of an environment variable as a [substitution argument](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args). That value can then be passed to your node as a [parameter](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2020-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jgdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1517/jgdo/) on 2020-04-28**:
Alternatively you can direclty read the environment variable in C++ using std::getenv()
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

**Comment by [harrynick](https://answers.ros.org/users/44792/harrynick/) on 2020-04-28**:
Thank  you soo much both :)